# Access defined variable of function in another function

Tags: r, function, api, inheritance, plumber

I am developing a Plumber Rest API where i have two function `simplequery` and `GetData`. So i want access or reuse variable **(studies)** in function `GetData` from function `simplequery` where I have used in function `simplequery` is`with function` with `parent.frame`

for example :-

**function simplequery**

```
simplequery<- function{
    with(parent.frame(),{
       studies <- get_studies(study_id = query) 
  
       associations <- get_associations(study_id = query)
  
       paste("Studies: ", n(studies), ",Associations: ", n(associations))
    })
}
```

**Function GetData**

```
GetData <- function(query=""){
  
  simplequery()
  # Get the data of Studies
  study_table <- studies@studies
  
  # Get the data of publication
  publications_table <- studies@publications
  
  # Get the data of genotyping_techs_table
  genotyping_techs_table <- studies@genotyping_techs
  
  # Get the data of platforms_table
  platforms_table <- studies@platforms
  
  list(study_table, publications_table, genotyping_techs_table, platforms_table)
}
```

After running the api I get the result from function `GetData` but unable to get the result from function `simplequery` getting error

**"Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()): object 'input' not found\n"**

i don't know where the problem is

Please Help!

Thank you in Advance

Comment: This is fundamentally not a good idea. Use *parameters* and *return values* to communicate across function calls. Don’t try to bypass these mechanisms.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have tried that too but It's not working. Thank you for your response